# "(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: " | Django, Gunicorn, Nginx - Server Error(500)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have deployed my django app, but have a 500 error. When i type in the home url "mysite.com", it comes with the error and does not load, but when i type in "mysite.com/careers", or "mysite.com/sell", which happen to be fully static pages, it comes up beautifully. The home page, and other pages which have dynamic data do not serve.
Afer reading some related questions, it seems to be a Gunicorn issue.
What could be the issue here? Below is the error log from Nginx.

Nginx Error log:

```
2019/12/16 17:30:15 [error] 20605#20605: *1370 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xx, server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "mysite.com"
```

nginx .conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_buffering off;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
...
}
```

nginx sites available file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/MySite;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/djangoadmin/pyapps/MySite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help in figuring this out. I'm almost there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of my issue was a failure to run new migrations on my server.
All of the pages that were effected were those which displayed data associated with those models, or for which they were a foreign key.
In finding the answer, I committed a grave production sin, which was to briefly turn Debug:On. I hope the programming gods forgive. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have something from this list of possible troubles:

1. you don't have gunicorn running because of any error or it was not just started yet.
2. You have your gunicorn process listening on another unix socket path or ip port.
3. your socket has incorrect permissions and nginx can't connect to it because of permissions issues

Comment: The odd thing is that some of the pages in the site do load when the url is manually typed; all of the static pages. In this case, could one of your theories still be the case?

Comment: Are you talking about static pages/resources?

Comment: I just mean pages in the website that are hard coded with no Django templating or dynamic data, when I say “static pages.”

Comment: what are the pages / resources urls?

Comment: I’m sorry, clarify what you’re asking? Im new to this. In my question, “mysite.com/careers” will work, but “ mysite.com” will not.